# Python/Pandas Walk through directory and save all foldernames subfolder and file to excel

Tags: python, pandas, os.walk

I want to save all directory info. (path, folder, subfolder, and files) to an excel spreadsheet using Pandas.

Here is my code so far:

```
import os
import pandas as pd


# setup the paths
root_path = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser("~"), 'Desktop/')
test_path = os.path.join(root_path, 'Test Dir')

# setup excelwriter
# Input writer
xlWriterOutput = pd.ExcelWriter(os.path.join(test_path,'read_directory_to_excel.xlsx'), engine='xlsxwriter')


files_list = []
dfFiles = pd.DataFrame

directory_path = os.path.join(root_path, test_path)

if not os.path.exists(directory_path):
    message = "Failed to find directory '%s'." % path
    if errors is not None:
        errors.append(message)
    else:
        raise IOError(message)
else:
    for path, dirs, files in os.walk(test_path):
        for file in files:
            files_list.append(os.path.join(path,file))
            dfFiles['path'] = path
            dfFiles['directory'] = dirs
            dfFiles['file_name'] = file

#Write the directory walk out to excel
dfFiles.to_excel(xlWriterOutput, header=True, sheet_name='Directory Output', index=False)
```

I started out with a list but started moving my solution to Pandas and ExcelWriter.  I get an error "*Type Error: 'type' object does not support item assignment*" on the line where i am attempt to set `dfFiles['path'] = path`.  Need some help at this point.

Answer (score 2):

you can use `pathlib module`:

```
from pathlib import Path

inp_path = Path('.') # specify the path here
df = pd.DataFrame([{'parent': f.absolute().parent, 'full_path': f.absolute(), 'relative_path': f,
               'file_name_without_extension': f.stem, 'file_name_with_extension': f.name} for f in inp_path.glob('**/*')])

df.to_excel('specify the excel sheet path here.xsls', index = False)
```

Here:

1. `parent` will give the parent directory info.
2. `absolute` will give the absolute path
3. `stem` will give the file name without extension
4. `name` will give the name of the file.

NOTE: If you want only file information you can add an if condition in `list comprehension` : `if f.is_file()`.